# BitsTransfer does not work on megatools using http or https on windows 7

Tags: http, powershell, https, download, windows-7

I have a question about using Bitstransfer on powershell in order to download data via https. The following code works well on powershell 5.5 of windows 10 while it does not work on powershell 2.2 or 4.4 of windows 7. In particular, the problem seems to be the use of specific website megatools.
Since the https works well even on windows 7.

```
Import-ModuleBitstransfer
Start-BitsTransfer-source "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Example.jpg"
```

If I try to download a file from https://megatools.megous.com/ for instance https://megatools.megous.com/builds/megatools-1.9.97-win64.zip it does not work both with https and http.

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop> Start-BitsTransfer -source https://megatools.megous.com/builds/megatools-1.9.97-win64.zip
Start-BitsTransfer : Unable to connect to server
On row:1 car:1+ Start-BitsTransfer -source https://megatools.megous.com/builds/megatools-1.9.97- ...+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-BitsTransfer], Exception    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartBitsTransferCOMException,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.NewBits   TransferCommand
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop> Start-BitsTransfer -source http://megatools.megous.com/builds/megatools-1.9.97-win64.zip
Start-BitsTransfer : Unable to connect to server
On row:1 car:1+ Start-BitsTransfer -source https://megatools.megous.com/builds/megatools-1.9.97- ...+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-BitsTransfer], Exception    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartBitsTransferCOMException,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.NewBits   TransferCommand
```

Can you explain me why?

Thank you

P.S. I reported the error to megatools maintainer and they said the following:

megatools.megous.com is served over https (TLS 1.2 is minimum allowed version of the protocol, also it uses cert with subject alt name and server uses SNI).
nginx server configuration
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

Answer (score 0):

After a very long analysis I found the solutions. In few word windows 7 does not support TLS v1.1 or v1.2 even if it is possible to install them.
I analysed the website with this test website https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/
The following is the configuration report for megatools.megous.com
Protocols

```
TLS 1.2     Yes    
TLS 1.1     No
TLS 1.0     No
Cipher Suites (SSL 3+ suites in server-preferred order; deprecated and SSL 2 suites at the end)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9f)   DH 4096 bits   FS     256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9e)   DH 4096 bits   FS     128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x6b)   DH 4096 bits   FS     256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x39)   DH 4096 bits   FS     256
```

while this one is the configuration report for mega.nz

```
Protocols
TLS 1.2     Yes    
TLS 1.1     Yes
TLS 1.0     Yes
SSL 3     No    
SSL 2     No
Cipher Suites (SSL 3+ suites in server-preferred order; deprecated and SSL 2 suites at the end)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     128
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa)     112
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcc13)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     256
```

and wikipedia.org

```
Protocols
TLS 1.2     Yes    
TLS 1.1     Yes
TLS 1.0     Yes
SSL 3     No    
SSL 2     No
Cipher Suites (SSL 3+ suites in server-preferred order; deprecated and SSL 2 suites at the end)
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     128
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9e)   DH 2048 bits   FS     128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9f)   DH 2048 bits   FS     256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     128
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     128
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc008)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     112
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc012)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     112
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x67)   DH 2048 bits   FS     128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x6b)   DH 2048 bits   FS     256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x33)   DH 2048 bits   FS     128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x39)   DH 2048 bits   FS     256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x45)   DH 2048 bits   FS     128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x88)   DH 2048 bits   FS     256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9c)     128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9d)     256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x3c)     128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x3d)     256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)     128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35)     256
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa)     112
```

I used this script https://gist.github.com/erotavlas85/289c38e7c076fda9349e in order to test Windows SSL capabilities and this is the output https://gist.githubusercontent.com/erotavlas85/2c251af8625a77cd7db1/raw/65c777ee60edc498382e826097cd3568bb0a2eac/SSL%2520output
Moreover, all TLS versions were already enabled, however I manually added windows registry keys following this https://palmarg.wordpress.com/2014/06/09/enabling-tls-1-2-using-powershell/
In any case the same output.
Finally, I informed the website administrator who reduced the security requirements of the web server via https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/ and now it works like a charm.